# How to split a space-delimited list of paths where paths can include spaces in .NET 2?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2005

For instance:
`c:\dir1 c:\dir2 "c:\my files" c:\code "old photos" "new photos"`

Should be read as a list:

- c:\dir1
- c:\dir2
- c:\my files
- c:\code
- old photos
- new photos

I can write a function which parses the string linearly but wondered if the **.NET 2.0** toolbox has any cool tricks one could use?

Comment: Am I correct to assume that the quotes `"` are the delimiters and if they are missing that the spaces are the delimiters?

Comment: what is  *.NET 2.0 toolbox* ?

Comment: Are you referring to the toolbox in visual studio?

Comment: I think you could do this with Regex but given you have to process each char in order I think linear would be fastest.  foreach (char c in dirlist.ToCharArray

Comment: Yup, a regular expression is probably the "simplest" you can get when you want to optimize caller code complexity. (And it shouldn't be too bad in terms of speed either when the regex is in compiled mode.) - @Blam: ToCharArray wouldn't be fast, you would make a copy of the input. IndexOfAny with a space and quote to find the next "interesting" offset would be a good option for speed, besides the obvious for-loop. In any ways profiling would be needed to tell the winner.

Comment: @Erno basically yes, anything between two quotes is considered one piece regardless if it has spaces, but you still have spaces even between two quoted strings e.g. `"old photos" "new photos"` not `"old photos""new photos"`

Comment: @Zarat Just because ToCharArray makes a copy does not mean it will be slower.  You know for sure IndexOfAny then extracting would be faster?

Comment: @Blam: I know for sure calling ToCharArray (making a copy) is slower than not calling it (not making a copy). Calling ToCharArray gains you nothing, any algorithm you wanted to do on the char array you could've done on the original string as well (unless it involved modifying the array, but your incomplete fragment only showed looping over it).

Comment: @Zarat If you think a two step - 1) find offset 2) extract phrase is faster then post your code and lets let the OP compare.  I posted a one pass.

Comment: @Blam: Your comment was incomplete (I assumed it was a mistake), it just loops and does not split the input. You don't even detect the required separators. To pass your results into stock .NET Framework the OP would need to reassemble the substrings from your char array, too.

Comment: How did this question turn into a (premature?) optimization discussion? Are these milliseconds that important?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have to hit every character I think a brute force is going to give you the best performance.
That way you hit every character exactly once.
And it limits the number of comparisons performed.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = @"c:\dir1 c:\dir2 ""c:\my files"" c:\code ""old photos"" ""new photos""";
    List<string> splitInput = MySplit(input);
    foreach (string s in splitInput)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
    }
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(input);
}

public static List<string> MySplit(string input)
{
    List<string> split = new List<string>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    bool splitOnQuote = false;
    char quote = '"';
    char space = ' ';
    foreach (char c in input.ToCharArray())
    {
        if (splitOnQuote)
        {
            if (c == quote)
            {
                if (sb.Length > 0)
                {
                    split.Add(sb.ToString());
                    sb.Clear();
                }
                splitOnQuote = false;
            }
            else { sb.Append(c); }
        }
        else
        {
            if (c == space)
            {
                if (sb.Length > 0)
                {
                    split.Add(sb.ToString());
                    sb.Clear();
                }
            }
            else if (c == quote)
            {
                if (sb.Length > 0)
                {
                    split.Add(sb.ToString());
                    sb.Clear();
                }
                splitOnQuote = true;
            }

            else { sb.Append(c); }
        }
    }
    if (sb.Length > 0) split.Add(sb.ToString());      
    return split;
}
```

Comment: Bah, can't get the IndexOfAny one right, it's too complex. Anyways, I'm not saying that a plain for loop can't be faster than IndexOf/IndexOfAny (I said profile!), and the StringBuilder is really clever - my issue with your suggestion was that you loop over ToCharArray instead of doing `for(int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) { char c = input[i]; ...` -- if doing the copy and working on char array is really faster than not copy and working on string indexer I have to admit I had a totally wrong idea about string performance.

Comment: After profiling I have to grant you that you are right and I'm wrong. Array indexing beats string indexing if I replace your for loop with what I had in mind and commented above. (Rest of your code stays the same.) -- do you have any explanation of why that is, or just figured it out by experimentation?

Comment: Yes I have an explanation but you still owe me a +1

Comment: Yeah, sorry, wasn't sure if it did fit the OP requirements so I had to reread it, I've first been understanding it as "simple way to split string with Framework tools" (where Regex would probably a good choice), but your answer definitely fits the "parse string linearly part".

Comment: Then write the Regex if you think it is faster.  With an overlap of delimiter (space in a ") seriously doubt it will be a one pass under the covers.

Comment: I neaver said that regex would be faster, I just consider it simpler than a hand written parser. I'm outa here, just wanted to give some suggestions for possible solutions, and you showed you know a better one, no need to keep arguing. I still think its totally not obvious that a copy + iterator is faster than ordinal indexing, but I guess its too much work for the JIT to optimize (with unsafe code - which wasn't part of the question, I know, not my point - ordinal indexing is indeed faster, so it's probably about the bounds checks the iterator doesn't need to do).

Comment: @Zarat Then write that Regex and post it as an answer.  If it works I will give it a +1.

Comment: Yeah, whatever, I've posted that regex, it's not that hard to come up with. Of course its slower, but it should not cause backtracking and its still easy enough to understand. No idea what your point is, though.

Comment: Since there is no 'clever' way to do this built into .NET, my preference would be the simple algorithm over the regex. I am not bothered by performance here, typical input length is at most a couple of thousand characters.

Answer (score 1):

Usually for this type of problem one could develop a regular expression to parse out the fields.  ( "(.*?)" ) would give you all the string values in quotes.  You could strip all those values from your string, and then do a simple split on space after all the quoted items are out.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string myString = "\"test\" test1 \"test2 test3\" test4 test6 \"test5\"";
            string myRegularExpression = @"""(.*?)""";
            List<string> listOfMatches = new List<string>();

            myString = Regex.Replace(myString, myRegularExpression, delegate(Match match)
            {
                string v = match.ToString();
                listOfMatches.Add(v);
                return "";
            });

            var array = myString.Split(' ');
            foreach (string s in array)
            {
                if(s.Trim().Length > 0)
                    listOfMatches.Add(s);
            }

            foreach (string match in listOfMatches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(match);
            }
            Console.Read();

        }
```

Unfortunately, I don't think there is any sort of C# kungfu that makes it much simpler. I should add that obviously, this algorithm gives you the items out of order... so if that matters... this isn't a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex-only solution which captures both space-delimited and quoted paths. Quoted paths are stripped of the quotes, multiple spaces don't cause empty list entries. Edge case of mixing a quoted path with a non-quoted path without intervening space is interpreted as multiple entries.

It can be optimized by disabling captures for unused groups but I opted for more readability instead.

```
static Regex re = new Regex(@"^([ ]*((?<r>[^ ""]+)|[""](?<r>[^""]*)[""]))*[ ]*$");
public static IEnumerable<string> RegexSplit(string input)
{
    var m = re.Match(input ?? "");
    if(!m.Success)
        throw new ArgumentException("Malformed input.");

    return from Capture capture in m.Groups["r"].Captures select capture.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a space acts as a delimiter between *except* when enclosed in quotes (to allow paths to contain spaces), I'd recommend the following algorithm:

```
ignore_space = false;
i = 0;
list_of_breaks=[];

while(i <  input_length)
{
  if(charat(i) is a space and ignore_space is false)
  {
    add i to list_of_breaks;
  }
  else if(charat(i) is a quote)
  {
    ignore_space = ! ignore_space
  }
}

split the input at the indices listed in list_of_breaks
```